# Windows Phone 8 SDK - Issue with screen locking, and application starting over

Tags: windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I have an application with a webbrowser control in it.  When I navigate in that control then step away for a bit, then come back to it (after unlocking the screen due to inactivity), the first/original page shows up again.  How can I maintain the state of the browser?

Comment: The scenario you're describing is usually called "tombstoning". You may be able to find some documentation by using this keyword. I'm not sure what is the best way to handle your issue, but I guess it involves saving the current webbrowser's URI when the application is deactivated, and restoring it when the application is activated. That wouldn't be enough to completely restore the browser's state (for instance, what the user has typed in forms will be lost), but I don't know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a public property Url in App.xaml.cs to store an Url

```
public Uri Url { get; set; }
```

On WebBrowser_LoadCompleted event: save WebBrowser.Source property which contains the current loaded Url to above Url property of Application class.

```
App app = Application.Current as App; 
app.Url = WebBrowser.Source;
```

On Application_Deactivated event (send app to background), save current app's state to IsolatedStorage

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
settings["Url"] = Url;
settings.Save();
```

On Application_Launching event (resume app), pull the stored data back

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
Url currentUrl;
if (settings.TryGetValue("Url", out currentUrl)) 
   Url = (Uri)settings["Url"];
```

Then from the restored Url, you can re-load the last navigated page.

```
App app = Application.Current as App;
WebBrowser.Navigate(app.Url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
bool isNew = true;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
     {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        isNew = false;
}
```

this property will be maintained until your page is closed, so you can use it to test if this is the first time your page is navigated to.