# Preserve WebBrowser Control state

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am new in WP8 development and I am making an app that has a WebBrowserControl to access to my website. I want to save the state of WebBrowser when app comes to background, but I can't do this (i.e. when user wants to re-open application WebBrowser will load last page seen).
My code, [based in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514046/windows-phone-8-sdk-issue-with-screen-locking-and-application-starting-over), is the following:

WebBrowser properties: Base and Source are empty.

**App.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    //Url to store current address to maintain state when application is in background
    public Uri Url { get; set; }
    //Boolean to get if phone has been previously in background
    public Boolean firstRun = true;

    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        Uri currentUrl;
        if (settings.TryGetValue("Url", out currentUrl))
            Url = (Uri)settings["Url"];
    }

    private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        settings["Url"] = Url;
        firstRun = false;
        settings.Save();
    }
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
 {
    Uri baseUrl = new Uri("http://my_url");

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser.Navigated += new EventHandler<NavigationEventArgs>(WebBrowserNavigation);
        App app = Application.Current as App;
        if (app.firstRun)
        {
            webBrowser.Navigate(baseUrl);
        }
    }

    async void WebBrowserNavigation(Object sender, NavigationEventArgs navArgs)
    {
        string url = navArgs.Uri.ToString();
        App app = Application.Current as App;
        app.Url = navArgs.Uri;
    }
```

Comment: How are you unable to accomplish this? What error are you getting?

Comment: When I push Windows button (bring to background) and I reopen the app, it reloads base_Url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing `bring it to the foreground` and `relaunching`.  To bring it back to the foreground press the back button after pressing the windows button.  You will see that your application is exactly where you left it.  If you re-launch the program by pressing a title or using the start menu, it will start a new instance of it... thus showing your base URL.

---

So basically FirstRun does not matter in your program.  When you launch your program you should grab the last URL by doing this

```C#
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    // this.FirstRun = true; // doesn't matter

    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    Uri currentUrl;
    if (settings.TryGetValue("Url", out currentUrl))
    {
        Url = (Uri)settings["Url"];            // got the last url
    }
    else
    {
        Url = new Uri(@"http://www.msn.com");  // last url not defined, set it to default base
    }
}
```

---

Save your Last URL in both events

```
// Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
// This code will not execute when the application is closing
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    settings["Url"] = Url;
    settings.Save();
}

// Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
// This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    settings["Url"] = Url;
    settings.Save();
}
```

---

And when your MainPage gets loaded navigate to the saved URL

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    App myApp = Application.Current as App;

    webBrowser.Navigated += new EventHandler<NavigationEventArgs>(WebBrowserNavigation);

    webBrowser.Navigate(myApp.Url);
}
```

---

Doing it this way, it always saves your state and it doesn't matter if you bring it to the foreground or launch it again from the title or start menu.  You can say that you properly `tomestoned` your WebBrowser URL at this point.

Comment: I'm going to try your solution and will tell you. I'm newbie in WP8 development ;). Thanks!

Comment: I changed all methods you told me and I kept Application_Activated method and bring to foreground works fine, but reactivation (press Windows and open app again) doesn't working; without this method either work. It could be because app clean cookies when is closed?

Comment: Get rid of the Application_Activated, you won't need it.  I think there is something else in your code that is conflicting with the `Closing` event.  Ok, to recap to bring it to the foreground: Hit the windows button, then the Back Arrow.   To close the application, just hit the Back Arrow.  I posted a minimal project to my one drive here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F2F16D176D29EFC!8398&authkey=!AGjuxnhJD07Hr1Y&ithint=folder%2csln  good luck, pay attention to the App.xaml.cs file as well as the MainPage.xaml.cs file.  Download it deploy and run.  It will goto google.com first.

Comment: At the search box type MSN or something, then click on that webpage.  Then close the application with the back arrow.  Relaunching the application, it will bring back MSN as it launch page rather than google.

Comment: I have discovered what was my error. I have an stack to store previous URL visited, and I don't save its state in Application_Deactivated and Application_Closing. Thank you very much!